# custom validator of checkbox in gridview only mark one row invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I have a gridview with 1 to 4 item checkboxes plus a checkbox to select "none" in each row.

On submit I am trying to return an error to a row if "none" and any other item is selected in a row.  I am using a custom validator which is working for the first invalid row, but does not error subsequent invalid rows.  When I correct the first invalid row and re-submit the validation method runs again and invalid rows are found, but the page is returned as valid.

How can I get the validator to error all invalid rows, or how can I set the page as invalid when an invalid row is found?

Update -  I found that this issue only happens when the last row is invalid.  If the last row is invalid the Page.IsValid flag is not set to false.  I also found that validation, noneChecked, runs once for each row; so if there are four rows it validates each row four times.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Items">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span class="qdsdata">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder12" runat="server" Visible='<%# !DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval("records"))%>'>
                            <asp:CheckBox ForeColor="#FF5050" runat="server" ID="cbr" />
                            Records<br />
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder7" runat="server" Visible='<%# !DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval("xray"))%>'>
                            <asp:CheckBox ForeColor="#FF5050" runat="server" ID="cbx" />
                            X-Rays<br />
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder8" runat="server" Visible='<%# !DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval("path"))%>'>
                            <asp:CheckBox ForeColor="#FF5050" runat="server" ID="cbp" />
                            Pathology<br />
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder9" runat="server" Visible='<%# !DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval("echo"))%>'>
                            <asp:CheckBox ForeColor="#FF5050" runat="server" ID="cbe" />
                            Echocardiogram<br />
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        <hr style="width: 60%;" />
                        <asp:CheckBox ForeColor="#FF5050" runat="server" ID="cbnone" ValidationGroup="valgroup1" />
                        None<br />
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="vcbnone" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" OnServerValidate="noneChecked"
                            ValidationGroup="valgroup1" CssClass="r" ErrorMessage="Uncheck None"></asp:CustomValidator>
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind

```
public void noneChecked(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in Location.Rows)
        {
            bool cbnone = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbnone")).Checked;
            bool cbr = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbr")).Checked;
            bool cbx = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbx")).Checked;
            bool cbp = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbp")).Checked;
            bool cbe = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbe")).Checked;
            if ((cbr || cbx || cbp || cbe) && cbnone)
            {
                ((CustomValidator)gvrow.FindControl("vcbnone")).IsValid = false;
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  I was looping through the gridrows each time the OnServerValidation noneChecked was called in the CustomValidator and it is called for each row in the grid, so if there are 4 rows in the grid it would loop 16 times.  I corrected this and the validation now works perfect.

New correct code behind:

```
    public void noneChecked(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)(source as Control).Parent.Parent;

    bool cbnone = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbnone")).Checked;
    bool cbr = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbr")).Checked;
    bool cbx = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbx")).Checked;
    bool cbp = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbp")).Checked;
    bool cbe = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbe")).Checked;
    if ((cbr || cbx || cbp || cbe) && cbnone)
    {
        ((CustomValidator)gvrow.FindControl("vcbnone")).IsValid = false;
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```